# WCF Data Services, Incorrect URI in returned data

Tags: rest, wcf-data-services

I am trying to deploy my WCF Data Services on a server behind a reverse proxy, in a subfolder, ie:
http://mydomain.com/mysubfolder/Services/WCFDataService.svc
And I reach my application like that: http://mydomain.com/mysubfolder/Default.aspx

There is actually a redirection from mydomain.com/mysubfolder to my server ip, it's not a VirtualDirectory configured in IIS.

My problem is that the URI of the objects returned are as follow: http://mydomain.com/Services/WCFDataService.svc/Articles(45) instead of http://mydomain.com/mysubfolder/Services/WCFDataService.svc/Articles(45)

Is there ay configuration that I missed or is this a bug?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Ah, that is a bummer, well I spent a lot of time on this and found a solution, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161853/wcf-data-services-error-302-moved-on-savechanges-related-to-https-load-bala